# Sweetalert shows half of the icon

Tags: sweetalert

I am using sweetalerts to send some kind of feedback to the users but for some reason when the popup appears the icon animates just half of it.

[image]

Does anyone know any reason why this would happen? I did not touch css of these components and installation guide was followed as usual.